# disabled styling for DIV element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to style disabled state for div I have code

```
<div disabled> Welcome </div>
<style>
    div:disabled{
      background-color:#f1f1f1;
    }
</style>
```

I don't have any class or ID present on the element. It is system generated. I want make the background color light gray.

Comment: div doesn't have enabled/disabled semantics. You don't have a div in a disabled state. You just happen to have a div with an attribute called disabled. That's why the :disabled pseudo doesn't work. If you want to add a pretend disabled attribute to your div, use data-disabled or something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use the Attribute Selector:

```
div[disabled]{}
```

See for more Information:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved using `attribute selectors`, in this case "disabled" is the given attribute:

```
div[disabled] {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

For more information, here is a very useful reference guide to using [data attributes on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Here is the specific guide on [Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

> Attribute selectors select an element using the presence of a given attribute or attribute value.

Answer (score 3):

In the div, `disabled` is an attribute. So use an attribute selector.

```
<div disabled> Welcome </div>
<style>
      div[disabled] {
         background-color:#f1f1f1;
      }
</style>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 2):

css to Attribute

```
div[disabled]{
     background-color:#f1f1f1;
  }
```